# How to install i386 library?

Tags: 32-bit

How to install or upgrade library i386 in Ubuntu server.
As shown below  for one server it showing i386 and for other version it is only showing i686 only

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.0.0-12-generic-pae #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 16:37:17 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 11.10
Release: 11.10

uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:32:08 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:        12.10
Codename:       quantal
```

Please help me with this....

Answer (score 1):

It will be hard, but I will give a try... (I have answered it once somewhere else as well.)

The only diference in a i386 build and a i686 build is sometimes in multimedia where MMX and SSE extensions are turned on during the configure process prior to building the package.

Thus, there is no difference what so ever in 95% of the packages.
The bottom like is all `i386` and `i686` packages are all 32bit.

So for all practicality `i386` and `i686` **are the same**!